# Is the Servlet path returned by request.getServletPath() guaranteed to be normalized?

Tags: java, security, servlets

1) Can `request.getServletPath()` return any path like `/testfolder/../testfolder/file.txt`, or is this path guaranteed to be **normalized**, thus converted to something like `/testfolder/file.txt`?

The reason I ask is because I want to know if this path can easily be used for access control. For example, when regular users should not be able to get access to paths that begin with `/admin/`, then some relative path like `/images/../admin/secretinfo.txt` could be used to circumvent this control.

Please note: Browsers convert any paths to absolute, normalized paths before contacting the server, but suppose other malicious clients that send relative paths could be used for an attack.

2) Also, are there other Servlet Path related security issues I should consider when performing this type of simple string verification access control?

Comment: These are both absolute paths, as they start with `/`. Your question is really whether the servet path is *normalized*, and the answer must be 'yes', otherwise the system would be unworkable.

Comment: Yes, normalized, not absolute. I edited the question to fix this.

Comment: The answer must be yes? If not, we could normalize it ourselves, so the system wouldn't be unworkable. I hope the answer is yes, but where is it written in the Javadoc, or Servlet specification? I must be sure and be able to prove it, so I need to see some official documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Servlet specification is unclear on this. There is an [open issue](https://java.net/jira/browse/SERVLET_SPEC-18) for this against the Servlet spec.

The specification strongly suggests it is normalized but for a security related application I would not rely on this and would run it through a normalization process to be safe. On that topic, I'd advise against rolling your own and suggest you re-use one such as [Tomcat's normalization code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/RequestUtil.java?view=annotate#l54).

Comment: However, Tomcat's normalization code in your link states that "This method is useful only for normalizing application-generated paths. It does not try to perform security checks for malicious input."

Comment: That comment is out of date. Over the decade or so since that comment was written the normalization code has been made robust. I'll try and remember to remove the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, this is not servletcontainer's concern. This is webserver's concern. A decent webserver will normalize it before hitting the servletcontainer. It *have* to, in order to locate the right resource.

The Servlet API can't guarantee this. It all depends on the webserver. I'd however be surprised if such a webserver exist as that would imply major security holes (think of security constraint URL pattern matching and such, those would otherwise very easily be circumvented this way).